# VBA - Conditional Formatting on Pivot Table based on offset value

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have a pivot table and I'd like to apply conditional formatting to one of the columns.  This should be based on the value in the cell to the left - if I was doing this manually in a normal worksheet, I'd use an offset formula.  I'm a bit stuck on how to do this with VBA and on a pivot table, though.  Having scoured the internet for code, I've ended up with this, but it's not having any effect.  The column I wish to apply the formatting to is called "WW volume", and is in column E.

```
 Dim PF As PivotField
    Set PF = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("WW volume")
    With PF.DataRange
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Yellow
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=VALUE(TEXT(OFFSET(E1,0,-1)))>0"
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
            .StopIfTrue = True
            .ScopeType = xlDataFieldScope
        End With

    End With
```

I'd really appreciate any ideas, I'm quite new at VBA.  Thanks :-)

Comment: I've now found a decent workaround, based on my recording of a macro:  `Range("E:E").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=VALUE(TEXT(OFFSET(E1,0,-1),""#,###""))>0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False`          So, not too woried about this question now.

Comment: That said, if anyone has a more elegant solution that would also allow me to exclude subtotal rows and total rows from the conditional formatting, I'm all ears.